# Como criar um limitador de .click() em JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou tentando criar um calendário em JS.

Primeiro fiz uma `<table>` que vai preenchendo as `<td>` de acordo com os dias, deixando todas disponíveis para clicar e selecionar um determinado dia. O usuário seleciona um dia de ida e outro de volta (mudando o estilo da data selecionada ao clicar) e as datas são redirecionadas para determinado `<input>`. E aí que está o problema, ao clicar em várias `<td>`, elas continuam mudando o estilo, sem um controle de clicks.

Isso é o exemplo de como estou fazendo para reconhecer os clicks:

```
function daysD(){
    $("td").click(function (){
        this.style.color = "#FFF";
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#65BC2B";
    });
}
```

Tem a possibilidade de controlar o número de vezes clicadas, para reconhecer apenas dois clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução**

Veja um exemplo de como poderia ser feito:

```
  $().ready(function() {
    var limit = 0

    $("td").click(function () {
        if (limit++ < 2) {
          this.style.color = "#FFF";
          this.style.backgroundColor = "#65BC2B";
        }
    });
  })
```

**Explicação**

Você pode utilizar uma `var global` dentro da sua função de `click`. Ela irá servir para contar a quantidade de vezes que foi clicado, com isso, basta fazer uma verificação do valor da variável com a quantidade desejada, e se a verificação for verdadeira, você executa os comandos que deseja no `click`.